# Mapview in tabbed application in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I would like to ask something, because as a beginner I do not have any idea anymore
how it could work.
First of all I made a new project, a single view one and added a simple map view.
This worked very well (following a tutorial of course)

Now I tried to add this simple map view to my inital project, which is a tabbed based on with navigation controller.
In this tabbed application I already added two more views with view controllers, and I called them thirdview Controller and forthview controller. The vc's I gave the class thirdview and forthview controller. 
So, now I wanted to make the mapview on the thirdview. I did exactly what I did in my "trial project" but it is not working. Well, when I run the simulator I see a map. But it does not show the location as I have specified it inn the thirdview controller.m

Because it was working in the singleview project, I guess I have something to add or to connect in my inital tabbed application?
I would be greatful for any help on this
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you show us some code? A lot of people here are amazing code-diagnosers. Way more so than me.

Comment: Yeah well, but it is really very simple code. And due to the reason that it worked in the single view application and not in the tabbed one with navigation controller I thought that the code can not be the problem but here it is.

Comment: thirdViewController.h I added #import "MapKit/Mapkit.h and the IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview; In the thirdViewvController.m I added the code                      {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled: YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    
    MKCoordinateRegion startregion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
    startregion.center.latitude = 52.547131;
    startregion.center.longitude = 13.404465;
    startregion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.08;
    startregion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.08;
    [mapView setRegion:startregion animated:NO];
}

Comment: But anyway it cant be the code. It worked very well in the singleView application. It has to be a setting in the tabbed application with navigation controll? I guess

Comment: Edit the code in your answer instead of putting it in a comment its unreadable like this!

Answer (score 1):

What you have there, as I can see from what you say, is a very simple and litle forget made by everyone who begins with xCode :)

Try to link your viewControllers and your map (in the xib or Storyboard) to your file's owner' view and delegate.

by default, these aren't linked. Just right click on it and drag your View and delegate to your file's owner.

Also, be sure that each of your viewControllers' classes are really thirdview and forthview in the properties (don't be confused with xib identifier!)

Hope this helped you! Feel free to ask if anything is missing :)

Comment: See? There are amazing people here!

Comment: Oh thanks for your answer. But how can I do this? Sorry that I do not understand how to link the viewControllers and the map to the file's owner view and delegate? The classes are proper set.

Comment: You can do it many ways. The easiest one is simply by using the right click on your File's owner. to go there open your xib or storyBoard, open the hierarchy view(in the bottom left corner of the xib window it's a blue or orange buble you can click on). there you have your file's owner. Right click on it. You will see to what is linked the "View" and the "Delegate". Maybe there will be old unused links. delete them and link them to your map. at this point, the white circle will be filled. I cannot be more clear and specific. Maybe you forgot to link your map as a Outlet to your viewController?

Comment: Ok, the thirdView Controller does have an outlet now mapview mapview, but it still does not work. The mapview has the referencing outlet mapView ThirdViewController..

Comment: I'm a bit confused, What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: sorry when I did not explane proper. Ok, I just want to add the mapview (working fine in the singleview application) to my tabbed application which has a navigation bar and a third and fourth view. So due to the reason that the map worked in my test enviroment I guess that some settings or connections are not right. But I really do not have a clue.

Comment: Okay, at this point I would suggest you that you redo the steps. Begin a new project. delete the default ViewController in the StoryBoard. Add your tabBarController. add a viewController. link it as a tab to your tabBarController. add a map to the viewController. At this point link your map as an Outlet to the viewController class. Then, right Click the map (in the viewController view) you will see DataSource and Delegate. Link both of them to the file's owner. test it. If it does not work, I can't really help you anymore...

Comment: Just a last hint. I now identified the following. As long as I have a singleView application with only the mapView, the map is shown as defined in the ViewController.m, with the start location (in my case Berlin).
As soon as I add a tabbar controller, the map does not get the information from the ViewController.m anymore, and starts at the default. 
Thanks a lot for any reply on this.

Comment: Oh right... Of course you need to attach your map as a IBOutlet to your .m file. You can't really do things with it otherwise!

Comment: Hey thanks! I guess it must be a Referencing Outlet from the map to the ViewController?
But when I try to drag and drop it does not allow it?

Comment: Xavier, it was already connected, but still not showing the right location. The referencing outlet is mapview -ThirdViewController